# How to convert a java collection of images to CvArr

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I want to use OpenCV's `FaceRecognition` in java through *javacv* wrapper library.
I don't know how to pass images and labels to `com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.FaceRecognizer.train(CvArr, CvArr)`

I can use `cvLoadImage(String)` or `cvLoadImageM(String)` to obtain single images, but how do I make an `CvArr` of them?

Answer (score 1):

After some [reading](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/basic_structures.html#cvarr) I found out that `CvArr` is an opaque type. You just initialize with any data - it is just a C pointer after all.
So:

```
CvMat[] images = new CvMat[n];
images[0] = cvLoadImageM(...);
...
CvArr arr = new CvArr(new CvMatArray(images));
```

Answer (score 0):

This post is about using the Contrib Module with JavaCV. It also explains how to pass the images to the wrapped functions:

- [Face Recognition on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699744/face-recognition-on-android/11700665#11700665)